# What is the name of this surface? (appears in a movie)

Tags: terminology, surfaces

In the intro of the movie "Pi: faith in chaos" appear many mathematical elements that I recognize like Möbius band. But this one I don't get it:
[image]

Obviously is a surface in the space, but what is its name? by the direction arrows and using the terminology of dynamical system I guess is used as attractor.

Comment: Take a look at note "c." on the Wiki page for the film.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [John Douma](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/69810/john-douma) pointed out in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796768/what-is-the-name-of-this-surface-appears-in-a-movie#comment7822198_3796768), a clue can be found in [note c of the English Wikipedia page for the film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_(film)#cite_note-15):

> Much, and even most ( if not all, ) of the mathematical imagery consists of graphical matter to be found in "Jahnke and Emde." That is the Dover Edition of Tables of Functions by Eugene Jahnke and Fritz Emde.

A version of that famous text can be viewed in the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/), and [here is a direct link](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.212842/page/n87/mode/1up) to the page (75) with (the [negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_(photography)) of) the image in question.

The text clarifies that it is a [relief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief) (showing the [magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(mathematics)#Complex_numbers)) of [the complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) $K(k)=\displaystyle{\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta }}}$ as a function of $\lambda=k^2$. A closely-related image, but for it as a function of $k$, can be found at [the MathWorld page for the function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html).